# InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme " gs"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

So, I'm tryting to grant access to a bucket from another project in order to import the data of that bucket int the project, I have used the command that the documentation suggests

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data#move_data_files_to_a_local_bucket

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:[DESTINATION_PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin \
gs://[SOURCE_BUCKET]
```

but when I use it

[image]

Is it just me or the Google Cloud Platform documentation is always really fuzzy on somethings ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it does not know scheme `\ gs` you should better call it `gs`.

The only thing you actually want to escape are line-wraps, not spaces.

Comment: Martin is totally right. That \ looks odd to me. Normally after that \ it is a  line break but that was not the case on your command so that is the reason for your error.

Comment: This probably once was a line-wrap, which had not been completely removed.

Comment: Thanks, but you are right that the documentation does not states clearly that that \ should not be there, is confusing